# Access php page using joomla vars but display like a pure php script (no template)

Tags: php, joomla

I have 'appsrv/newrequest.php' inside joomla root dir.

How can I call newrequest.php without using joomla template but using joomla framework vars?

Deleting the row below will output the php script but no access to joomla vars?

```
defined('_JEXEC') OR defined('_VALID_MOS') OR die( 'Restricted access' ); //security reason
```

I tried to use a blank template:
http://mysite.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=153&Itemid=40&template=blank

and here the content of index.php of the blank template:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
include('../cgi-bin/appsrv/epr/newrequest.php');
?>
```

the method with template works, but it's not good for because I have many scripts and that means I have to create for every script - a separate template...

Is there any other method?

Comment: What exactly do you need it to do and/or display? Making a custom module is probably going to be the way to go here.

Comment: I am embedding a php script into joomla article. And I am using ajax to return some value: but I get article title, etc for ajax output, but not what I need.

Comment: But...did you just posted twice the same text in your question or am I seeing double? Anyway, if you store php text in the database, it will be returned as string, therefore useless. The right way is using a template system. The wrongest possible way ever is using eval(). But don't.

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: sorry :) corrected

Comment: Kind of risky to use framework vars without the validation of JEXEC. It indeed allows to execute the script without going thru Joomla's index.php, but also, if you execute the script alone, you won't have the joomla vars at hand because you didn't pass thru joomla componentresolving process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.subclosure.com/howto-access-joomla-session-variables-from-another-php-file.html

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1701888